# Is there a query way to select a table with multiple items with columns to show but one column to show all from the table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a two tables joining to show a list of items and currently it goes something like this.

> SELEC tableA.item1, tableA.item2, tableB.item3, tableB.item 4, tableA.item5 FROM tableA INNER JOIN tableB ON tableA.item2 = tableB.item1 WHERE tableA.item1 = A

And shows like this

```
item1    item2    item3    item4   Item5
  A       Z        1        0.1      B1
  A       Y        2        0.2      B2
  A       X        3        0.3      B3
```

However I want it to show one column, for example item1, to show all items that are in the tableA. Such as like this

```
item1    item2    item3    item4    item5
  A       Z        1        0.1      B1
  A       Y        2        0.2      B2
  A       X        3        0.3      B3
          W
          V
          U
```

Something like this. Is there a way like SELECT *item1, item2 FROM tableA, etc.

Comment: The first output section is incorrect for the query, because of the where clause. Would suggest changing INNER JOIN to LEFT JOIN to achieve what you're asking.

Comment: Only `item3` would be having null values due to the inner join

Comment: But what do I add in the select item to show the rest.

Comment: You've edited this post once or twice since my earlier comment; How about you add sample data from each of the two tables referenced in the query, plus what output you're hoping to get back from your query - then someone may be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `Union`?

```
SELECT tableA.item1, tableA.item2, tableB.item3, tableB.item 4, tableA.item5 FROM tableA INNER JOIN tableB ON tableA.item2 = tableB.item1 WHERE tableA.item1 = A
UNION
SELECT NULL as item1, item2, NULL as item3, NULL as item 4, NULL as item5 FROM tableA
```

Answer (score 0):

Use LEFT OUTER JOIN instead of INNER JOIN to get the items in tableA with no match in tableB.

Comment: Changing LEFT OUT JOIN is making my query not work since i need that item2 = item1 to show, i think.